# selecting which columns to be used for indexing and whether they should be clustered or non clustered

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 & creating a table that will have 8 columns, types shown below. I am trying to assess which columns I should use as indices and whether they should be clustered or non-clustered indices.

Once a day (normally) there will be an upload of approx 10,000 rows of data. Going forward its possible it could be 100,000.

```
type             column name
-------------    ------------
datetime         UploadDate
varchar(12)      SecID
varchar(6)       FundCode
varchar(100)     Name
float            Price
float            Nominal
int              SourceCode
datetime         PriceDate
```

example of a some rows

```
UploadDate   SecID    FundCode   Name   Price   Nominal   SourceCode   PriceDate
2015-08-20   A045     ABCVPL     Joe    1.3434  1000.33   3
2015-08-20   A563     ABCVPL     Bob    1.5961  10.33     3
2015-08-20   A045     DEFGHJ     Joe    1.3434  856.41    3
2015-08-20   XC45     PLMNOI     Pip    2.3654  25.52     3
2015-08-20   KMM5     ABCVPL     Nit    6.9565  1532      3
2015-08-21   A045     ABCVPL     Joe    4.3434  1112      3
2015-08-21   GH45     DEFGHJ     Joe    3.3434  16532     3
2015-08-21   PL34     DEFGHJ     Joe    7.3434  635       3
2015-08-21   ER33     ABCVPL     Joe    8.3434  6320      3
```

An overnight process will insert new rows into the database so the time taken here is not an issue.

It will just be select queries being run on the table & there will be no primary key.

If we take 1 day as an example of the data. Lets say today there are 10,000 rows being uploaded. The column UploadDate will be 21st Aug 2015 for all 10,000 rows. The FundCode column can take on 20 different values. All the other columns (apart from SourceCode - although don't think this will be queried much) will have different values and pretty much take on infinite values.

So I believe FundCode & UploadDate would be two columns that could possibly be candidates for indexing does that seem correct? If so should they be clustered or non-clustered and why?

**Update**

Just to add that using the first three columns as an index would create a unique row - not sure if that helps or anything

Comment: Kimberly Tripp [show quite clearly what a **good** clustering key is](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) - do follow her advice! She's the *Queen of Indexing* !

Comment: There are already articles with general advice about how to index on the internet, and to give specific advice, we would need to know what queries are going to be run, and how they should be weighted.

Comment: Also: *there will be no primary key* - that's a **horribly bad idea** - every table **ought to have** a proper primary key allowing you to clearly and reliably identify each row on its own. Typically, that primary key is also the **clustered index** in SQL Server

Comment: To underscore what @Tab said: What queries will be run against this table? What queries will be run most frequently against this table?

Comment: There will only be select queries run on this table. I imagine must queries will be based on the UploadDate and the FundCode. So for example a select where the where clause specifies a date range for a certain fund code

Comment: @marc_s In this case then what column would you make for a primary key. Does every table then need to have a primary key? I'm just going through the link you sent, thanks

Comment: So put the clustered index on UploadDate and FundCode.   Anything else?

Comment: Since I really don't know what your data looks like (and you haven't provided any clues to that nature), I cannot really tell. A PK **must be** non-nullable and unique - and since it by default becomes the clustered index, too, it should be *NUSE* - narrow, unique, stable and ever-increasing. So unless `SourceCode` is all those things, I would most likely add a *surrogate* `TableNameID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` to the table to simplify things

Answer (score 0):

1. When you create a primary key on any column or combination of columns, it creates a clustered index
2. You cannot have more than one clustered index on a table
3. Rest of the columns, on which you will do search most of the time, create non-clustered index on them

   - Create the primary key on first three columns first
   - Create non-clustered index on those columns which you will use mostly in your search criteria

Comment: You cannot have more than one clustered index **on the table**

Comment: Sql server only creates a clustered index for a primary key if there is not already a clustered index on the table.

Comment: so the best way would be to create a primary key on UploadDate, FundCode & SecID. By default this will be a clustered index. Is using those 3 columns for my primary key acceptable. I keep reading primary key should be as narrow as possible?